# ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm getting ER_PARSE_ERROR when question mark (?) is added into message variable.

**My code :**

```
 socket.on("chat message", (data) => {
      const { sender, receiver, message, ad_id, category_id } = data;


      const sql = `INSERT INTO tbl_user_chats (sender,receiver,message,ad_id,category_id) VALUES (${sender}, ${receiver}, '${message}', ${ad_id}, ${category_id})`;
      con.query(sql,data, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
      });
```

**Error :**

```
 code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1531', `receiver` = 735, `message` = 'yeah fine, and you ?', `created_at` = 1663' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO tbl_user_chats (sender,receiver,message,ad_id,category_id) VALUES (1531, 735, 'yeah fine, and you `sender` = '1531', `receiver` = 735, `message` = 'yeah fine, and you ?', `created_at` = 1663745307202, `ad_id` = 182, `category_id` = 3', 182, 3)"
```

If i not add message by excluding question mark (?) it works and inserted into table.

How to fix the parse error when i include question mark character in my message ?

Comment: The error message is pointing to the value before  `'1531' ..` and judging from your `INSERT` syntax, it's seems as if you're doing `UPDATE` instead.

Comment: but it works, if i not include question mark (?) character into my message.

Comment: In which part of your code that you remove `?` and make it work?

Comment: variable message holds a string when ? marks come to the string it results error for example.
message = "Hello"    - this works,
message = "Hello ?" - this gives error

Comment: See this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/SvgT94Wh .. I've run the exact query shown in the error message and I get the exact error starting from that position; before `'1531' ...` .. and there's no `?` before that. If you correctly wrap your value with quotes, MySQL will treat `?` as string; 1) this is acceptable `'yeah fine, and you?'` . 2) this will return error `'yeah fine, and you' ?`.

Comment: Let me ask you this, what were you planning to do with these values ```.. `sender` = '1531', `receiver` = 735, `message` = 'yeah fine, and you ?' ...``` from your `INSERT` statement? The generated `INSERT` statement should be like this instead https://dbfiddle.uk/0watySas - see the second example.

Comment: see, this is a chat application, so i use socket.io, the data variable contain datas like sender id, receiver id, message , ad id, category. im trying to insert that into chat table.

Comment: How did you generate the value for `${message}` variable? Because it seems like the other  variables are returning fine except for that one.

Comment: this also returning fine, but when ? character comes into this make error.

Comment: Could you do `console.log(message);` before `const sql =.. ` command and tell us what does it return in the terminal?

Comment: Yes that prints the message as : How are you ?,

Comment: I think I see the problem, your `const sql` statement includes all those variables and you also do `con.query(sql, data ..`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never add external input into queries directly (search "SQL injection").

Instead, use the [escaping methods](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) provided by the `mysql` library:

```
const { sender, receiver, message, ad_id, category_id } = data;


const sql = `INSERT INTO tbl_user_chats (sender,receiver,message,ad_id,category_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`;
con.query(sql, [ sender, receiver, message, ad_id, category_id ], ...)
```

Comment: Is this `const { sender, receiver, message, ad_id, category_id } = data;` being used at all?

Comment: @FanoFN yes, it declares the variables used in `con.query()`

Comment: Thanks @robertklep, everything ok u saved me

Comment: If instead the code is like this ```const sql = `INSERT INTO tbl_user_chats (sender,receiver,message,ad_id,category_id) VALUES (?)`;
con.query(sql, data, ...)``` will it work @robertklep ?

Comment: @FanoFN `con.query()` expects an array, not an object.